What's the purpose of philosophy/knowledge?
Nietzsche said something like "argument/dialectic is the weapon of the weak, as the strong simply do what they wish and don't need justifications for it."
From Twilight of the Idols, the whole section on 'The Problem of Socrates', but especially §5-6:

"With Socrates, Greek taste switches over in favour of dialectics: what is actually going on here? Above all it means a noble taste is defeated; with dialectics the rabble comes out on top. Before Socrates, dialectical manners were disapproved of in polite society: they were seen as bad manners because they were revealing. The young were warned against them. People also mistrusted any such presentation of one's reasons. Respectable things, like respectable people, do not wear their reasons on their sleeves like that.
....
You choose dialectics only when you have no other means. You know that using it provokes mistrust, and that it is not very convincing. Nothing is easier to dismiss than the effect a dialectician produces: the experience of any assembly where speeches are made is proof of that. It can only be an emergency defence in the hands of those who have no other weapons left. You must need to force your being in the right out of people: otherwise you do not use it."

What's the point of learning Deep Understanding, Inquiry, knowledge, philosophy?

Academic Agent (Youtube) has a video wherein he says there are two political arguments with what appear to be a major premise, a minor premise, and a conclusion. First argument. Blah blah. Blah blah. Therefore, I deserve to rule. Second argument. Blah blah. Blah blah. Therefore, my decisions were correct. Hebrew scripture uses these terms: the Lord, God, and the Lord God. These are designed to transform the ruling consciousness in man. Nietzsche thought it is an attribute of animal and human nature that the strong rule the weak and don't have to justify their actions. It is not always true.

@armand see the evolution of religion society culture nation....

Your general question is very broad, and different philosophers and schools of philosophy have answered these things differently.  Nevertheless, I will take it from your invocation of Nietzsche that you are interested in answers that explain his own philosophy, so I will try to provide an outline of what he thought on these issues.
Nietzsche was sceptical of much philosophising (particularly that which led to religious Judeo-Christian ethics) and he believed that greater progress towards understanding could be made by observing and accepting the "will to power" that is the basic drive of each individual.  Nietzsche saw much of formal philosophy as simply a post hoc justification and codification of modes of behaviour that were really generated by the will to power of different types of people --- in particular, the strong who adopt forms of "master morality" based on aristocratic ideals, and the weak who adopt forms of "slave morality" based on the ethics of altruism (but based psychologically on ressentiment).  In Beyond Good and Evil, Nietzsche argues that most of what passes for deep inquiry and philosophising in his day is just an ex post facto rationalisation of the moral codes that the philsophers want to get to a priori as a formulations of their needs, interests and insecurities.
Nietzsche was in favour of learning, deep understanding, knowledge, etc. (and was certainly very learned himself), but he believed that this knowledge should be "worn lightly" and that it should be an adjunct to instinct and the will to power (rather than a rationalising mechanism that pretends to be a primary cause).  The anti-dialectic quotations you give here are consistent with his general view that a healthy person with noble tastes and mindset should have strong implicit instincts and should act in a health manner primarily by instinct and will.  Deep learning and knowledge assist this by cutting through the illusion and sophistry.

Dialogue from First Knight dramatizes these philosophical arguments: https://youtu.be/qWDUzjwI9_A?t=84. Malagant: The strong rule the weak! That's how your God made the world. Arthur: God makes us strong only for a while; so that we can help each other. Malagant: My God makes me strong so I can live my life! The film Indiana Jones and The Last Crusade (1989) has a scene where young Jones contemplates a clue: Only in the leap from the lion's head will he prove his worth. Dominant male lions drive out young males from the pride. Those males become strong and drive out old males in turn.

The point of deeply understanding things, gaining knowledge and think philosophically about it (that is, evaluate the learned lessons to learn even more from it), is a phenomenon of our (modern) society. It serves an important role to foster our culture and heritage, it enables us to invent things, that never existed before, enables us to reflect upon ourselves, helping us to form our identity and gain meta-knowledge by thinking about thinking and what lies beyond our understanding.
All-in-all it could be said that those "mental actions" have no real "worth or meaning" (they are not tangible, unless written down) in terms of "physical actions" which just "happen" and have an immediate, visible/noticable effect. The thinking about it is either done prior (aka "planning") or afterwards (aka "retrospective evaluation or judgement").
"Mental achievements" are the product of some people who had the luxury of time and freedom/peace (and ability/skill) to use their brains more than their muscles. I think this is the reference to the aspect of "only the weak need words" -or have only available those-  and the "strong just can use their strength and the swords (weapons)". [swords-words, nice pun]
I have the early stages of mankind in mind: Living was surely more violent than nowadays. You were in constant fear and danger of being eaten, finding not enough food, shelter, etc. you name it. At this point gaining knowledge and understanding things surely did take place, but were more focused on the pure survival. To some extent the philosophical parts might have been present as well or developed quickly, for example to sort out things like "possession" of objects, or "rank in society" (who will be the next shaman, who will be chief), and also maybe judging about being "guilty of a crime" (against said rules of possession, and the punishments for it, like being expelled).
In those days, having strength and raw power, not being hesitant (aka not thinking to much) to make use of it and also apply them to your own kin or other "tribes" to dominate them, was "the" way of doing it, of achieving things, live and survive. So you might argue, those were the "strong" ones. (But without someone who did the thinking, they alone surely would have eradicated themselves or all of mankind over time.)
Given the achievements and development of social structures, humankind were able to "clear out a less violent spot", like in a village for example. Maybe primarily, because there were the "strong" who were able to protect others and ensured the survival of many. In those villages the "brain" using people had their chance to shine and bring the whole lot of people even more forward, for example by inventing things like the wheel, controlling of fire, irrigation, observing the sky and flow of the seasons and other stuff. Which in turn also the "strong" ones benefited from.
Fast forward to the greeks, were a certain Sokrates, being more the "brains" type of human, had enough time at hand to ponder about the world - and especially about logical structures in spoken words. He invented the "dialectics" because he realized, that people around him tend to think "illogical". And to show them, he went out to the streets and talked to them (hence dialectics, from dialogue). He revealed their misconceptions and proved into-their-face being absolutely wrong, because of their logical contradictions in their conclusions and thoughts.
You can imagine how admired and popular he was, especially if - I make that up: - he tried to convince a musclepacked ("strong") Hercules that he was sharpening his blade in the wrong manner and that he actually stole the apples of the hesperides, which is a crime, and should return them and apologize. [cynism intended]
Therefore, he might have realized, that he has to be amongst those who are willing to listen and understand - and not amongst those who are willing to punch him, if he applies his kind of "power" to them.
I would argue, that Sokrates (or Nietzsche for that matter), was wrong in concluding the words are only for the "weak"... Because they can be equally powerful as the weapons supposed to be wielded by the "strong".
But you cannot argue that the one or the other is more important, as I tried to make clear with the development of mankind. Both ways co-exist until today, because both ways made it possible to live up to this point. Sure, one of them is far less violent, but might also cause high amounts of pain.
Having the opportunity to delve into science and philosophy is an achievement we gained over all the time mankind exists. They are essential to us and our living into the future. They allow us to gain and preserve knowledge to give along to our descendants, which have the opportunity to do the same. And probably, as sad, devastating and disappointing as it might be, living the violence also is.

Nietzsche, per my reading, employs a specific model in his philosophy, that of the slave-master duality. The OP focuses on one side of this coin, viz. the POV of the masters, which boils down to might is right (re: the word "weak" in the OP).
From a moral standpoint, some have interpreted Nietzschean duality to favor the slaves less than the masters. How much of that is read into, i.e. subjective, rather than read from, i.e. objective is an open question.
I didn't realize he had such a dim view of Greek philosophy, foundationally dialectical, but if he's making an argument, he's inviting the dialectician over for coffee so to speak. If he's not making a case for his philosophy then it's just opinion; it'll resonate with some folks, with some it'll not.
It's also said that he subscribed wholly to Darwinism, its competition elements struck a chord in him I suppose. Becoming/existing ubermenschen is/are thrust in our faces as a total/final solution to all of humanity's woes.
He presents a (personal) report on humanity, neatly tucked within a slavery-themed dichotomous framework. He likely doesn't give recommendations/suggestions/advice; most claims that he does are probably instances of subjective hermeneutics.

@andrós, tough call. Je ne sais pas. He was definitely not doing what Kant did/was doing. If I may say so, he was trying to include the latest that science had to offer (it was Darwinian evolutionary theory) into his views on human history (dominated by God, specifically Christianity) and left it to the reader/audience to infer/guess what everything was leading up to. Nevertheless he was explicit about God's passing.

@andrós, I find Heidegger inscrutable, but he was a metaphysician after all, oui? He, from what I could gather, was trying to unite sky and earth; the horizon is an illusion, oui? Que sais-je.

Nietzsche's "master" type  is all about freedom, and recognizing your own freedom; it's not about enslaving people.
Nietzsche says that the overman is aware that his experience is not limited by the bounds of reason or justice. The overman knows he is free to push people around and  and beat them up.
But Nietzsche never says you OUGHT to do that. Everyone ignores that fact. In Zarathustra, Nietzsche said, "You know that you are capable of evil, therefore I expect from you the good."

The Dionysian/Apollonian distinction is more primordial for Nietzsche than the Master/Slave distinction.
Here is a quote from the (2019) book Full Throttle Heart: The Rapture & Ecstasy of Nietzsche's Dionysian Worldview, §10 Idea II – The “Aristophanes-Moralizing Complaint” (p. 38).
"In a notebook entry from 1869 (a “posthumous fragment” [eKGWB/NF-1869, 1(44)] regarding Nietzsche’s essay “Socrates and Greek Tragedy”) Nietzsche wrote the following two comments: “[I] will show Aristophanes was right: Socrates was a sophist” and “Euripides, the dramatic Socrates.” That Nietzsche [also] elaborates these ideas [later] in 1888 points to the consistency of his philosophy – from before The Birth of Tragedy to The Anti-Christian.
The birth of tragedy as an interpretation of the meaning of existence produces heroes. From the point of view of tragedy, it is possible to interpret the meaning of your existence and govern your life-decisions in terms of sacrifice. You have already been granted existence; along with being granted existence, you have been subjected to the riddle of existence: In your heart, what do you find worth dying for? Afterall, that is what you are going to do; now that you have been granted existence: die. Therefore, your answer – your response – to the riddle of existence is inevitable. And, by way of your response, you reveal the rank and order of existence to which your soul belongs."
Specifically, in regard to the quote at the beginning of your question, Aristotle actually said something very similar, which is not surprising, since Aristotle is also where Nietzsche gets the idea of "the herd" and "herd mentality" from. So, rather than ask, "what is the point?" it may be better to ask how is it that our learning (or lack of learning) has hindered our ability to ascend to the Dionysian worldview. Or, how has "learning Deep Understanding, Inquiry, knowledge, philosophy" (or lack thereof) allowed passive (nihilistic) forces to separate our active forces (will-to-create/Wille-zur-Macht) from what they can do. If you want to speak in terms of goals, then the goal for Nietzsche would be to ascend to the Dionysian Worldview and be able to say Yes to existence. Be able to say: Amor Fati.

Knowledge produces a model of the world. That's what is essential about having knowledge.
Without knowledge, you die (e.g. you feel thirst but you don't know that turning the tap knob over produces water). But survival is not just sleeping and drinking. It is also winning an argument (e.g. otherwise, you get into prison), conquering a woman (otherwise, your genes end with you), etc. Making science is necessary for medicine or spatial research, both of them impacting survival at different scales of time.
Philosophy is then required to organize, collect and use all the necessary information to create knowledge.
The term dialectics is used in philosophy at least in six ways. But in general, it is no more than a particular approach of developing knowledge.

This, but the phrase 'conquering a woman' could use an edit. How about 'starting a relationship with a woman'. You could also make it gender neutral, as women need a model to attract men as well.

The "point" is that the top of thought is a contentious place.  Everyone wants to be there, you could say, for the views it has.  There are a privileged few throughout history who have made great vistas by creating the syntheses that united previously disparate views and then had the fine experience of luxuriating in them for some time of their life before creating the tension for the next generation to fight over.
The only ethical tool one has available for these "battles" is reason and dialectic.  When this fails, verbal or physical violence is the only remaining solution to the problems of entropy -- which is where we find ourselves now with opinions of Truth being our downfall as a society.  At no other time in history, has Man been so weak on the issues of Truth, hence the continued importance of philosophy.  Even if every other man were to die, the importance of the Truth that remained would be enough to save him/her.
